# Would a Muslim pray during a dangerous situation?

Tags: science-fiction, religion

I'm writing a short scifi story in which a small group of people are trying to escape a failing space station.

The characters need to go through a dangerous part of the station. One of them is a Muslim and I was wondering whether a devout practitioner would do a prayer before attempting it. And if so, what would that look like to an outsider? There isn't much time, so it would have to be done very quickly.

Him being a Muslim doesn't really affect the story, its just small detail. I just want to portray the character correctly and respectfully.

Comment: Sorry about my answer about daily prayers - I misread the question as would they do a daily prayer at that time if it happened to coincide with the danger, since that's a commonly observed part of islam. I think it'd be personal whether they decide to do a "Hey look after me as I do this dangerous thing" prayer but I don't know for sure. There are probably actual practicing muslims here who would answer this better than I could.

Comment: Yeah, no worries. I know practically nothing about Islam so I ask to make sure I write a realistic portrayal. I know a Christian would probably put their hands together and ask God to watch over them. But I don't know if Islam has any similar prayers or even if that's a thing for Muslims. The question is actually twofold: would a Muslim really do a prayer in that situation and if so, what it would look like.

Comment: This question isn't really about world building, and would best be asked on the Islam stack exchange.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you ask an Imam, or post this question on [islam.se].

Comment: I agree that this isn't about worldbuilding, however I've held off voting to close until now - when you have two good answers. (From review).

Comment: In hindsight you are probably correct and I should've asked this on Islam. World building already had couple of answers to similar questions I was wondering about, so it didn't even occur to me that this wouldn't be the correct place.

Comment: @Rottweileronmarket-day. actually it should be opposite: don't answer questions which clearly do not fit Worlbuilding, not "don't close questions just because they have answers"

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica On reflection I agree. The Sandbox might have been better ultimately, considering the recent comment after Trioxidane's answer. It seems that the question as-written, is in fact not the question the OP wanted the answer for. Perhaps could have been crafted to be on-topic.

Comment: Even a devout Atheist will pray at a moment like this.  And not all prayer is visually obvious. Many Catholics, for example, "work prayerfully", meaning everything they do during their shift, including undertaking a dangerous part of a mission, is done with love and compassion for the other person, in this case, fellow space station crewmen. I don't know about Muslim prayer life, but certainly something akin to that could be taking place and never be obvious to the others.

Comment: You might like to ask your question here https://islam.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Does "Oh, God! Oh, God! Oh, God!" count as prayer? Barring the regularly scheduled prayers and prayers for specific occasions, like the Eids and funerals, Muslim prayers are not ritualised. All that is required is to remember Allah while putting in your efforts and acting in a manner consistent with Islam. If muttering a prayer while focusing on saving yourself works, then by all means you are free to do so. Maybe a pause for breath, while saying "Bismillah" or "Innalillhahi wa inna ilaihe razeun", much like a Catholic might make the sign of the Cross, but the latter is a bit funereal.

Answer (score 6):

**Probably not**

From my talks with the Iman at the mosk near my house I would say no. This is in the Netherlands though, so they might be relatively liberal.

When we were talking I wondered if there were exceptions to rules, like eating pig. The man told me that they were a practical religion. If eating pig is something that can save you from starvation, you can eat it. Same for things like Ramadan. If you have a valid reason not to participate, you don't have to. Some possible examples are pregnant women, recovery from injury, an eating disorder or burn out.

The question you ask isn't as easily answered though, as it isn't just one single religion. Just like Christianity, there are loads of forms and ways to practise the religion. It is likely that there are some forms that would condemn you for eating pork while starving. Someone from a very strict form of Islam might do the prayer in your situation, although I don't see a reason for the prayer except the danger. No one would sit down for a prayer if a bear comes to maul you.

So from my talk with the Iman I gather that they value the practicality of surviving over sitting down for a prayer. That being said, he might still be able to say or think his prayer during whatever needs to be done surviving.

Comment: This strikes me as an ideal reference answer.

Comment: The idea is that while the situation is dire, they have a few seconds to brace themselves before they have to venture into the dangerous place. So all the characters do what come natural to them before embarking into danger. Someone mutters encouraging words to themselves "you can do this, you can do this" and so on. I was wondering whether a Muslim would instead say a short prayer (or even if they have a short prayer).

Comment: @Qualdan Now I understand what you're after, take a look at the [Misbaha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prayer_beads#:~:text=In%20Islam%2C%20prayer%20beads%20are,cycle%20through%20them%20three%20times.), it's a short description, but apt I think.

Comment: @Qualdan that isn't exactly clear from the question. It seems a wholly personal thing to pray at that time. So whatever is best for your story.

Comment: @Rottweileronmarket-day. I did find that in my initial search, but I understood that it required 99 prayers, which doesn’t fit into the timelimit.

Comment: @Trioxidane I may have used weird wording, but I did say “I was wondering whether a devout practitioner would do a prayer before attempting it.”

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they do; at least in the [*Thousand Nights and One Night*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_of_the_Thousand_Nights_and_a_Night) (a.k.a. the *Arabian Nights*) they do.

here is an excerpt for the *Story of the Third Beggar*, a sub-story of the famous *Story of the Porter and the Three Ladies of Baghdad*:

> Then, being minded to make a longer voyage upon the ocean, I fitted out half a score ships with provision for two months and sailed twenty days, till one night the wind blew contrary and the sea rose against us with great billows; the waves clashed together and there fell on us a great darkness. So we gave ourselves up for lost and I said, "He who perils himself is not to be commended, though he come off safe." **Then we prayed to God and besought Him**, but the wind ceased not to rage and the waves to clash together, till daybreak, when the wind fell, the sea became calm and the sun shone out.
> <sup>(*Arabian Nights*, English translation by [John Payne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Payne_(poet)), 1901. Volume I, p. 122.)</sup>

---

A real-life addition by user Damian M Hallbauer:

In fact it's extremely common and part of everyday Muslim life, essential to say in the moment before doing something critical. Just before running through the collapsing hallway, have the character say: *"Bismillah-ir-Rahman-ir-Rahim"*. Muslims of all languages would say this in Arabic, and Muslims all over the world will appreciate this detail immensely, as even not-that-devout Muslims will know and recognize this much Arabic.

Saying the Bismillah prayer when anxious before doing something critical and irreversible, is nearly as common as a Christian who prays only when they are terrified for their life, or saying "Oh my God", or "Lord have Mercy" or something like that.

The phrase means the following but no one would say it translated, as prayers are done in Arabic: "I begin in the name of Allah, the most beneficent, the merciful".

For more details on the origin and meaning of the phrase see the Wikipedia article on [Basmala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basmala).

Another less common but used in other situations is: *“Bismillaah, allaahumma innee a‛oodhu bika minal-khubuthi wal-khabaa’ith”*, “O Allah, I seek refuge with you from all evil and evil-doers.”

More on this topic on the [Quran Academy Blog](https://quranacademy.io/blog/bismillah-ir-rahman-ir-rahim/).

Comment: Maybe they were praying WHILE trying to save the ship? Most people believing in a divinity (and quite a few atheists) would do the same.

Comment: @DuncanDrake: Yes, of course, maybe. That is what the question asks: *"pray[ing] during a dangerous situation"*.

Answer (score 1):

**Anyone might pray in such circumstances!**

Have your character stop to say a few words to God thanking him for his many blessings and asking Him to guide his hands in this thing he is about to do.

His nonreligious crewmate hears this and nods.  "God, what Ali said just now - me too please!"

Comment: My point was that I don't know HOW a Muslim would do this kind of a prayer (or even what it would look like). I know how a Christian would do such a thing, but I have no knowledge about practicing Islam.